# How to update data across several days in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've got a database of approximately 315,000 records, which spans the course of several weeks, and an entry for every 5 seconds. In my database, I have an event (an instrument calibration) that happens every day at the same time (say, 6am). I'm trying to find a way to apply the calibration factor to the surrounding records.

I have columns for Julian Day (day of year is the actual value), Photons, Time (H:M:S), and elapsed time (in seconds and fraction of an hour).

So far, I have tried:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE Conc SET Calfactor =(SELECT AVG(Photon) FROM Conc WHERE trim(hms)
 BETWEEN '06:03:00' AND '06:06:00' GROUP BY JulianDay)  
 WHERE trim(hms) BETWEEN '05:00:01' AND '07:00:00';")
```

The subselect, if executed on its own, will successfully pull a list of averages across all days. My problem is that when I try to apply this list to the surrounding times, I cannot get it to match the day. SQLite wants to apply the first value it computes to all days. Of course, trying to apply GROUP BY or ORDER BY JulianDay throws an error. Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: why not just pull the list and then do a second sqlite executemany command to update the values? that seems like it would be easier (I dislike huge complex sql queries myself ... too error prone and hard to debug imho)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that when I need to optimize my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Conc
    SET Calfactor =(SELECT AVG(Photon)
                    FROM Conc Conc2
                    WHERE trim(hms) BETWEEN '06:03:00' AND '06:06:00' and
                          conc.JulianDay = conc2.JulianDay
                   )  
    WHERE trim(hms) BETWEEN '05:00:01' AND '07:00:00';
```

I'm not sure what the last `where` clause is for -- it seems to be updating records one hour before and after that time.  I'm leaving it in because it is in your sample query.

Comment: Worked perfectly--thanks! Yes, it's applying the calibration factor to the surrounding sample.